# Laravel 5.2 session flash working on localhost but not working on server?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

Session flash working fine on local but not working on server in Laravel 5.2?

In controller:

```
Session::flash('key', value");
return Redirect::to('/');
```

In view:

```
@if (Session::has('key') && Session::get('key')!='') 

alert('.......');

@endif
```

Comment: Make sure you have the proper driver configured on `config/session.php` and `.env`

Comment: what is   'domain' => null in config/session.php

Answer (score 0):

read this  :https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

```
Route::post('user/profile', function () {
    // Update the user's profile...

    return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
});
```

in view/blade

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```